# wappalyzer can't show the version of framework , plugins and wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, frameworks

I installed wappalyzer extenssion on google chrome to test my wordpress website 
but it can't show the version of wordpress , framework or plugins 
as I test any other websites like as wordpress or joomla it show me the version of wordpress , framework or all there plugins 
but when I test my site it can't show any version of them
please help me why 
this is my wordpress website address `http://mehrmagazin.ir` 
please take a look and help me why it can't show the version of wordpress , framework and plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wappalyzer can't show you the version because you have the plugin `Visual Composer` and as it the meta tag `generator` become `Powered by Visual Composer - drag and drop page builder for WordPress.`.

The pattern used to detect the version of a wordpress installation is matching the meta tag `generator` with `WordPress( [\d.]+)?\\;version:\1` (see [apps.json](https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/share/apps.json#L3519) in the github repository) so the version field won't match.